# Не работает s2s на xmpp-сервере

Tags: debian, dns, xmpp

Не работает s2s на xmpp-сервере на debian. Никак не могу понять в чём дело, пробовал prosody - ничего не получилось, сейчас ejabberd, та же проблема. Локально на домене всё работает, но при добавлении контактов с других серверов не происходит авторизации. Рабочий сертификат от letsencrypt. В записях DNS есть две SRV записи:

```
_xmpp-server._tcp.mydomain.ru. 86400 IN SRV 5 0 5269 mydomain.ru.
_xmpp-client._tcp.mydomain.ru. 86400 IN SRV 5 0 5222 mydomain.ru.
```

Они успешно отображаются сервисом https://kingant.net/check_xmpp_dns.
В логах ejabberd вот что:

```
2016-09-18 09:03:52.542 [info] <0.445.0>@ejabberd_s2s:new_connection:456 New s2s connection started <0.474.0>
2016-09-18 09:03:52.595 [info] <0.474.0>@ejabberd_s2s_out:log_s2s_out:1315 Trying to open s2s connection: mydomain.ru -> gmail.com with TLS=true
2016-09-18 09:04:11.414 [error] <0.474.0>@ejabberd_s2s_out:srv_lookup:1215 The DNS servers
  [{{127,0,0,1},53},{{46,28,201,21},53},{{46,28,201,22},53}]
timed out on request for "gmail.com" IN SRV. You should check your DNS configuration.
2016-09-18 09:04:50.198 [info] <0.474.0>@ejabberd_s2s_out:open_socket:271 s2s connection: mydomain.ru -> gmail.com (remote server not found)
2016-09-18 09:04:55.180 [info] <0.474.0>@ejabberd_s2s_out:handle_info:990 Reconnect delay expired: Will now retry to connect to gmail.com when needed.
```

Это пример соединения с xmpp-аккаунтом на gmail.com, с другими серверами тоже самое.

С prosody было аналогично. Что касается DNS - вроде бы все необходимые записи сделаны. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После общения с тех.поддержкой компании, предоставляющей VPS, случайным образом нашлось решение: xmpp-серверам критично содержание и порядок записей в `/etc/resolv.conf`. Было:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 1.2.3.4
nameserver 1.2.3.5
```

(где 1.2.3.4 и 1.2.3.5 - ip адреса dns-серверов)
Изменил на:

```
nameserver 1.2.3.4
nameserver 1.2.3.5
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

И ejabberd сразу стал успешно авторизироваться с другими серверами:

```
2016-09-18 15:16:08.784 [info] <0.455.0>@ejabberd_s2s:new_connection:456 New s2s connection started <0.462.0>
2016-09-18 15:16:08.785 [info] <0.462.0>@ejabberd_s2s_out:log_s2s_out:1315 Trying to open s2s connection: myserver.ru -> gmail.com with TLS=true
2016-09-18 15:16:09.516 [info] <0.449.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:313 (#Port<0.6902>) Accepted connection ::FFFF:74.125.113.32:53716 -> ::FFFF:1.2.3.6:5269
2016-09-18 15:16:09.775 [info] <0.462.0>@ejabberd_s2s_out:wait_for_validation:434 Connection established: myserver.ru -> gmail.com with TLS=false
2016-09-18 15:16:30.178 [info] <0.472.0>@ejabberd_s2s_out:wait_for_validation:510 wait for validation: myserver.ru -> gmail.com (closed)
```